# Align a bootstrap navbar to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to move my navbar to the right, tried both navbar-right, and pull-right, but all I get is something like this -

[image]

```
<div class="container" >
<h1 align="center"><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
<div class="container" >
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right" >
  <li class="active"><a href="#">tab1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">tab2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">tab3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">tab4</a></li>  
 </ul>
</div>
<br>
Hello

</div>
```

So there are 2 problems here - 
The grey line underneath the tabs is much shorter, and the tabs themselves aren't aligned properly - I want "tab1" to be the rightmost one, and correspondingly "tab4" the leftmost one.

I get the same results for navbar-right and pull-right. How can this be fixed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can easily have that behavior by just extending the Bootstrap.

[image]

Demo on JSBin: http://jsbin.com/zaniz/1/edit?html,css,output

all I did was added a `right-to-left` class to the `<ul>` and the CSS Style should be:

```
.right-to-left li { float: right; }
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why adding style="float: right" to the <li> elements doesn't fix this?

Comment: sure it does... but you should not repeat yourself ;) and I do think you are adding the `style="float:right"` to the `<a>` instead of `<li>` after the first. demo code: http://jsbin.com/zaniz/2/edit?html,css,output - if you are using `pull-right` that might not work because of inherit rules, a `float:left` might be last in CSS code that will override the `pull-right`...

Answer (score 4):

I've added the following rules to solve the problem without losing the border on the ul or reordering the markup:

```
.nav-tabs-right       { text-align: right; }
.nav-tabs-right > li  { display: inline-block; float: none; }
```

you can apply that to .nav-tabs directly but I prefer to create a separate class to replace .navbar-right

Answer (score 2):

You can try this; if you want that gray line to cover the entire page horizontly

```
<div class="container" >
<h1 align="center"><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
<div class="container" >
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" >
  <li class="active pull-right" ><a href="#">tab1</a></li>
  <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">tab2</a></li>
  <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">tab3</a></li>  
  <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">tab4</a></li>  
</ul>
</div>
<br>
Hello

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just added a `float: right;` (equal to `pull-right`) style to the `<ul>` and it seemed to produce the desired output, as for the tab1 being the rightmost one, it's probably best to reorder your markup to say:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right" >
    <li class="active"><a href="#">tab4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab1</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: For some reason adding float: right to the style still gives me the same result, what am I missing?
As for reordering the tab order, I guess I'll do that if there's no elegant way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap 5 you can simple add `justify-content-end` to the `<ul>` class

```
<div class="container" >
<h1 align="center"><a href="#">My Site</a></h1>
<div class="container" >
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-end" >
    <li class="active"><a href="#">tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">tab4</a></li>  
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
Hello
```