# How to align tabs to top/right in bootstrap 3?

Tags: tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to align bootstrap 3 tabs to right instead of left.

Is it possible with usage of bootstrap css or do I need to use custom css ?

Answer (score 31):

Use the class `.navbar-right` to push an element to the right within a navbar, or `.pull-right` to do the same when not in a navbar.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Good to know the other helper-classes here too: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes

Comment: Works right as long as you add a `<div class="clearfix"></div>` immediately after the `</ul>`

Comment: @eladcm is correct - just add new class and set `.nav-rtl li` to `float: right` - BTW: @Christina had great comment about stacking to accordion.

Comment: For me, it makes the text float off the right edge of the screen -- seems kind of broken. -- Also, it pushes the rest of the page down horizontally. -- I want it at the top right of the page, regardless of what else is there.

Answer (score 24):

use pull-right class:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active pull-right"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Tab2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Simplest solution! It even brings all the borders without breaking the alignment.

Comment: but it reverses the order of the tabs (tab2, tab1 and home is the rightest)

Answer (score 19):

Using .pull-right does this, it's undesirable:

[image]

What you want is this:
[image]

You need to adjust some stuff:

http://jsbin.com/zuxol/1/

HTML

```
  <div class="right-tabs clearfix">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab_a" data-toggle="tab">Tab A</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_b" data-toggle="tab">Tab B</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_c" data-toggle="tab">Tab C</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab_d" data-toggle="tab">Tab D</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_a">
            <h4>Pane A</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
                ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_b">
            <h4>Pane B</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
                ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_c">
            <h4>Pane C</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
                ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_d">
            <h4>Pane D</h4>
            <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames
                ac turpis egestas.</p>
        </div>
</div><!-- tab content -->

</div><!-- end right-tabs -->
```

CSS

```
.right-tabs .nav {
    float: right;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
.right-tabs .nav li { float: left }
.right-tabs .tab-content {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Comment: also, Bootstrap tabs don't collapse to accordion, you may want to look into this: https://github.com/okendoken/bootstrap-tabcollapse

Comment: Worked Thanks ♥

Answer (score 15):

I know it's an old post, how ever the soultion is simple :

CSS

```css
.nav-rtl {
    padding-left:40px;
    padding-right:0px;
}

.nav-rtl li {
    float:right;
}
```

HTML

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-rtl" role="tablist">
    <li ..... ></li>
    <li ..... ></li>  // an so on
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my time

Answer (score 7):

In case someone here is looking for an answer using **bootstrap 4**:

You can add `ml-auto` to the tab you want to push to the right

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs small" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#first" role="tab">First</a>
    </li>
    <!-- .ml-auto: adds margin to the left of this tab, all tabs behind this one, are pushed to the right -->
    <li class="nav-item ml-auto"> 
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#second" role="tab">Second</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#third" role="tab">Third</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[bootstrap docs: auto-margins](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#auto-margins)

Comment: yes, worked for me (all Tabs on right side plus border correct) - but do not understand why ...  Loocking for a other solution. Found `justify-content-end`, whitch have to be added on `ul`.

Comment: @SarahTrees You should post that as an answer - it's the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: `.ml-auto` (AKA `margin-left: auto`) just adds as much margin as possible between two tabs,  so you can have a few on the outer left and also some on the right side. If you use `justify-content-end` it moves `all` the tabs to the right. the same would work for `.mr-auto`, or you could even use `.mx-auto` to center one of the tabs as it adds margin on both sides

Answer (score 2):

Create a new class for Right alignment and use below css.

```css
/* overwrite boostrap */

.nav>li {
  float: none!important;
  display: inline-block!important;
}
/* new class */

.nav-tabs-right {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 0;
  /* prevent floated child bug */
}
.nav-tabs-right>li {
  display: inline-block;
  clear: left;
  float: none;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container jumbotron">

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-right">
    <li class="active">
      <a data-toggle="tabs" href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a data-toggle="tabs" href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. I wanted to know, how do I put a header to the far left of the pulled right nav-tabs?

Answer (score 1):

A very simple and good solution is described already here by balexandre:

[Align a bootstrap navbar to the right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297047/align-a-bootstrap-navbar-to-the-right)

```css
.right-to-left li {
  float: right !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<h2>Bootstrap tab aligned right</h2>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs right-to-left">
  <li role="3" class="active"><a href="#">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li role="2"><a href="#">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li role="1"><a href="#">Tab 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

(not that the tabs are ordered reverse)

Answer (score 0):

To use right aligned tabs, just add `.text-right` to the `.nav-tabs` class.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs text-right nav-tabs-highlight ">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also override by your container

```
<div class="someclassintabscontainer">
<!-- Here the tabs code writed normaly -->
</div>
```

Write this in some css file.

```
.someclassintabscontainer .nav-tabs > li {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add class justify-content-end

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-end" role="tablist">
</ul>
```