# Align right-aligned navtabs with header element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a right-aligned nav-tab with bootstrap 3

```
<div class="col-md-12 comments-header">
    <h3 pull-left style="display: inline">1 Comment</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs"
        <li role="presentation" class="active pull-right">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
            <a href="#">Messages</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- comments-header -->
```

The solution provided by [How to align tabs to top/right in bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24942637/how-to-align-tabs-to-top-right-in-bootstrap-3) partially works, except that unable to position the header comment aligned with the tabs

[image]

I tried very way to integrate `<h3>` into the tabs line, but the tabs actually occupy the whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit:

```html
<div class="col-md-12 comments-header">
  <h3 class="pull-left" style="display: inline;">1 Comment</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li role="presentation" class="active pull-right">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
      <a href="#">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="pull-right">
      <a href="#">Messages</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `<h3>` tag did not have the "pull-left" specified as a class, and the `<ul>` did not have a closing bracket on its opening tag. The revised above should float the "1 Comment" to the left, and pull the tabs to the right.