# Bootstrap 3 Navbar elements not aligned properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The elements are aligned properly when I run my website **locally**. This is the expected result:

[image]

However, On my [Webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20170527163023/http://kaushayaganguly.com/), the elements are aligned to the left.
 I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297047/align-a-bootstrap-navbar-to-the-right) but it's still the same. What I don't understand is why is it working on my local machine and not on the server? How do I fix this?

 Related HTML code :

```
<section id="header" class="appear">
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-0="line-height:100px; height:100px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);" data-300="line-height:60px; height:60px; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="fa fa-bars color-white"></span>
                </button>
                <h1><a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" data-0="line-height:90px;" data-300="line-height:50px;" style="font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;">           Kaushaya </a>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav right-to-left" data-0="margin-top:20px;" data-300="margin-top:5px;">
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-about" >About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#testimonials">Work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-skills">Skills</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#section-contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.webparadiso.wordpress.com">Blog</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Did you try to add class `pull-right` on `<ul>`?

Comment: Just did. Doesn't work. I tried what @ProDexorite suggested and now it's on the right but I'm still not getting the expected result!

Comment: Should be `.navbar-right` instead of pull-right. Example ul: `nav navbar-nav skrollable skrollable-between navbar-right`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `float: right;` on both `.nav` and `.navbar`.

For additional adjusting on a vertical basis, you can use `clear: both;` on `.nav`. If it still does nothing, add `!important` at the end of the float statement. A Simple CSS solution for your problem!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey I did what you suggested and check out what I have now http://www.kaushayaganguly.com . The good thing is it's on the right, but doesn't look as expected. Check the image I provided above!

Comment: Adjust it with padding or margin and change the color of it by applying the CSS stylizing to `.nav > li a` so it goes to just menu links.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use twitter bootstraps nav classes to pull it to the right.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
```

You can see the example on the bootstrap site http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default